# Change a file while redirecting it as stdin input to a command

Tags: bash, io-redirection

In Bash, while running `mycommand < myfile`, I modify `myfile`'s content.

What content of `myfile` does `mycommand` get?
Does `mycommand` get the original content of `myfile` when i started running it, or does it get the modified content of `myfile` along with my modification?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what `mycommand` does. If it sleeps for 10 minutes then starts to read its standard input, it will see your modifications if they have already been done. If it does a first read of part of the file, then you modify the file, and it does a second read, it will see changes that are beyond the point that is has read.

Also, because of the buffering used by many programs, when you think your command has only read 1 line, it may have actually read much more (a "buffer-full", typically 8192 bytes).

Note, however, that editing programs often delete a file and recreate a new file with the changes. In that case your program will still use the old deleted file contents, and not see any changes. This is because when you open a file, the filename is converted to the unique "inode" that it corresponds to, and you no longer need the filename. If someone removes the file, this inode continues to survive as long as something still has it open. When a new file is created with the same filename, it will get a different unique inode.

Comment: I was thinking also about vi/whatever editing, and file changes, and how caching (and caching management) would impact the readings.

Comment: I would sugest explaining why/how the program is still using a deleted file for novice Unix users.

Comment: Does how much the original content `mycommand` gets depend on how much the kernel "read ahead" the file into cache?

Comment: The kernel does not do the readahead. The standard C library provides buffering for input, which many programs choose to use for efficiency.